# Upperbound confusion

Tags: asymptotics

Why is the following true?

$3n^2-100n+6$ is big $O$ of $n^2$

This has been demonstrated to be true when $c$ is $4$ and $n$ is $10$.

$3*100-1000+6 = -694 = 694$ is the absolute value
is a big $O$ of
$4*100 = 400$

It looks like $n^2$ is a lot less. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you taking the absolute value of $-694$?

Comment: @user222031 According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) I should do that. I'm not really sure how to go about it though.

Comment: Oh the definition I use goes like this: $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ if there exists positive constants $c, n_0$ such that $0 \leq f(n) \leq cg(n)$ for $n \geq n_0$. How did you find your $c$ and  $n_0$? How do you know they are valid with your definition?

Comment: @user222031 ok can you provide an example using that definition? I can't find why the example in my question is true. If we're not getting the absolute value, is it because -694 is less than 400?

Comment: I graphed it, and if your $c = 4$ your $n_0$ should at least be $15$

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are confused as to the definition of "big $O$".  (either that or I'm confused)

$f(n)$ is big $O$ of $g(n)$ means $f(n)/g(n)$ is bounded.  Since in your case $f(n)/g(n)=\frac{3n^2-100n+6}{n^2}$ converges to $3$, it is bounded.

I don't see where "$c$" comes into it.

Comment: more likely I'm confused. As I understand it, f(n) is big O of g(n) if there is a constant and some large value of n that when you do c*g(n) is always greater than f(n).

Comment: Yes you are correct.  So since the limit $f(n)/g(n)$ is 3, you can take $c=4$ and then there must be an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)/g(n)\leq 4$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: f(n)/g(n)≤4 I'm not sure, do you you mean divide it?

Comment: I mean if a sequence $a_n$ converges to $3$ that for sufficiently large $n$ we must have $a_n< 4$.  You can replace $4$ by $3.00001$ if you want, as long as it's bigger than $3$.

Comment: ok, but I'm still confused when n = 10 in my question. And I think the answer to f(n) is -694. Is that really the right value?

Comment: Big O really is for comparing two functions that are non-negative, or at least are both non-negative for all but finitely many (initial) values of $n$.  In your case the first few values of $f$ may contain negatives but it doesn't matter because at some point it becomes positive and you look for your constants after that point. The point is that for all *sufficiently large* $n$ the bound $c=4$ holds.  That implies that there is a universal bound $C$ that works for all $n$ since there are only finitely many $n$ that don't work for $c=4$.

Comment: so that's it. for few values of n it would be really negative. I thought we should get the absolute values of the negatives. So in my example, the relationship is true. Do you find anything else wrong in how I check the formula?

Comment: Yes, don't mention $n=10$, that's just one value and you need the whole tail, so just say for $n>>0$ we can take $c=4$.

Comment: @user222031 Right, because that means there's another value of $c$ that works for all $n$.  Usually you don't need that value of $c$ though, the one that works in the limit is almost always enough for whatever purposes one is using big O for.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. Just to confirm, did you get the limit 3 from 3n^2? And since 3 is the limit, any c greater than 3 would be fine?

Comment: @user235991 Yes, that $3$ is why the limit of the ratio goes to $3$, it's crucial however that the power of $n$ is $2$ on both sides, if it was $3n^3$ on the left and $n^2$ on the right then it would not be big O, the limit of the ratio would be infinity.

Comment: what if it's the opposite. 3n^2 on the left and n^3 on the right?

Comment: @user235991 Then it would be Big-O. Since the limit approaches 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the following definition of $f(n)$ in Big O $g(n)$: $f(n)$ in Big-O $g(n)$ if there exists positive constants $c, n_0$ such that $0 \leq f(n) \leq cg(n)$. Ok consider the functions $f(n) = 5n^2 -20n + 12$ and $g(n) = n^2$.
$$f(n) = 5n^2 -20n +12$$
$$ \leq 5n^2 -20n + 12n,\ \ n \geq 1$$
$$ \leq5n^2 - 8n $$
$$\leq 5n^2$$
So, this is valid for $n_0 = 1$. So $5n^2 -20n + 12 \in O(n^2)$ because $0 \leq 5n^2 -20n +12 \leq 5n^2$ for $n_0 = 1$.

Now I'll use the other defintion to verify the same thing:
$$|f(n)| = |5n^2 -20n +12|$$
$$\leq |5n^2| + |-20n| +|12|$$
$$\leq 5|n^2| + 20|n| + 12 $$
$$\leq 5|n^2| + 20|n^2| + 12|n^2| , n \geq 1 $$ 
$$\leq 37|n^2| $$
So, this is valid for $n_0 = 1$. So $5n^2 -20n + 12$ in Big O $n^2$ because $0 \leq |5n^2 -20n +12| \leq 37|n^2|$ for $n_0 = 1$.
A specific constant $c$ and $n_0$ aren't really important, but the existence is what matters.

Comment: Ok, sorry I should've said this earlier. I am blind and I am using a screen reading software to read texts for me, but not mathematical symbols/notation and images. Do you mind changing your examples to a more textual format? For example, right now, my screenreaders reads "f(n)∈O(g(n)): f(n)∈O(g(n))" as "f(n) unknown symbol O(g(n)): f(n) unknown symbol O(g(n))". Thanks.

Comment: @user235991 Does it read the less than symbol?

Comment: not yet. If it's the less than symbol, is it like this < ?

Comment: @user235991 Yes, I meant this symbol though $\leq$.

Comment: my screenreader read that as "equals". do you mean <= or just <

Comment: I'll post the same answer with the latex removed.

Comment: @user235991 absolute value

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the following definition of f(n) in Big O g(n): f(n) in Big-O g(n) if there exists positive constants c, n_0 such that 0 < f(n) < cg(n). Ok consider the functions f(n) = 5n^2 -20n + 12 and g(n) = n^2.

f(n) = 5n^2 -20n +12

< 5n^2 -20n + 12n, n > 1

< 5n^2 - 8n

< 5n^2
So, this is valid for n_0 = 1. So 5n^2 -20n + 12 is in Big-O n^2 because 0 < 5n^2 -20n +12 < 5n^2 for n_0 = 1.

Now I'll use the definition that you use to verify the same thing:
absoluteValue(f(n)) = absoluteValue(5n^2 -20n +12)

< absoluteValue(5n^2) + absoluteValue(-20n) +absoluteValue(12)

< 5absoluteValue(n^2) + 20absoluteValue(n) + 12

< 5absoluteValue(n^2) + 20absoluteValue(n^2) + 12absoluteValue(n^2) , n > 1

< 37absoluteValue(n^2)

So, this is valid for n_0 = 1. So 5n^2 -20n + 12 in Big O n^2 because 0 < absoluteValue(5n^2 -20n +12) < 37absoluteValue(n^2) for n_0 = 1.
A specific constant c and n_0 aren't really important, but the existence is what matters.

Comment: thanks a lot! Really apreciate this :)

Comment: what's this \ \ for?

Comment: @user235991 Yeah, no problem. Gregory Grant's explanation with the limits is more practical but it seemed like you found the c and n yourself, so I posted an answer showing you how to find them.

Comment: @user235991 I removed it from the post. It shouldn't be there...